# I am having the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

My TypeError seems to be based around groupSize, but when I remove the int in front of the input I get the same error but with strings elsewhere.  I tried to simply convert the variable when defining sort, but that didn't help either.  Not sure how to fix this.

```
import random

groupSize = int(input('How many numbers are we sorting today?'))

numSet = random.sample(range(0, 999999), groupSize)
print('Our set of numbers is' + str(numSet))

def sort(arr, i, j, k):
    for i in j:
        for k in range(0, j-i-1):
            if arr[k] < arr[k+1]:
                arr[k], arr[k+1] = arr[k+1], arr[k]


sort(numSet, 0, groupSize, 0)
```

Comment: `for i in j` makes no sense since `j` is an integer and not an iterable (list/set). Maybe what you want is `for i in range(j)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this line: `for i in j:` it means `for i in 2000`. That's nonsense for python. I guess to you meant that `i` will range from 0 to j. For that you should use `for i in range(0,j)`, like you did in next loop

Comment: that totally worked. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "for i in j", change to "for i in range(j):